# Android Studio open tabs not showing

Tags: android-studio

Android studio used to display open files as tabs but it is not getting displayed (picture attached). How can I bring it back ?

[image: Open tabs not showing]

Just for the reference, it used to be like

[image: How it should be]

Comment: can you add full screen shot?

Comment: Check the setting : `File > Settings > Editor > General > Editor Tabs`

Answer (score 2):

For Window users:
Window-> Editor tabs-> Tabs placement->Top (or something different from none)

Answer (score 1):

I had this issue and I set it up by following.

On **Mac**:

1. Go to `Android studio Preference -> Editor -> General -> Editor Tabs`
2. Set `Appearance` to **Top**.
3. Apply
4. Ok

Reference screen shot as following.

[image]

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

If you have md plugin installed then try to uninstall that.
In my case it worked properly

Answer (score 0):

Just go to settings and then search for editor tabs and enable it.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).